# un able to connect my database to visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

hey, i`m stuck on it.. plx help..

my database is created on mssql 2008 and have connected on sql server compact edition and not on windows authentication.. can any body please help me out..

Comment: No, without more and better information nobody is going to be able to help. MS-Sql (Express) and Compact Edition are not the same, an neither of them is an alternative to Windows authentication.

Comment: …and the title references Visual Studio, while the body of the question doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 0):

in SQL Server Compact Edtion you dont have authentication like sql server 2008 so it is not possible but you can convert it to compact but it doesn't have sql server authentication or security for web application. you usually use it for package your product on CD.